If statement in batch doesn't see the data of the variable and just skips to else
I have a batch I use to map network drives.  I decided to add to the script setting icon variables. If the variables are set to "y" then later in the script I wanted to add shortcuts based off of the variables.  Currently, after mapping a drive I have this code that checks to see if the drive is available and then sets the variable UserIco=y or n to later use in the script.
rem This line is used to check if the drive letter works. And this line of code does work.
cd U: && (Echo Mapped Drive is accissble) && set UserIco=y || (net use U: /d) && set UserIco=n

I found in an if statement later that the variable UserIco is not working.  I put in echoes and stripped the statement down to this basic format.
Echo %UserIco%
IF "%UserIco%"=="y" (
Echo UserIco is %UserIco%
pause
) Else (
Echo Went to Else
pause
)

The variable %UserIco% echoes as "y", but the the if statement goes to else.

I'd start by modifying your positioning of parentheses, and of double ampersands instead of single ones: CD /D U:\ 2>NUL && (Echo Mapped drive is accessible& set "UserIco=y") || (%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use U: /delete & Set "UserIco=n"). As you can see, I've also used the /Drive option with CD, along with the root of the drive letter designator, \. I have also used the official /delete option for net.exe, (instead of just /d).

 set UserIco=y || (net use U: /d)
This will set UserIco to y , not to y.
The syntax SET "var=value" (where value may be empty; in which case var becomes undefined) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces on the source line are NOT included in the value assigned.
This is might have been evident in your code had you added Echo UserIco is +%UserIco%+ in your else routine to display the actual setting of userico when the routine failed. Note the +…+ "fences" around the subject string, which makes it easier to see invisible characters like Space
